# Difference between “At the time” and “at the moment”

Tags: grammar

What’s the difference between “At the/that time” and “At the/ that moment”?
In which cases should they be used?

Answer (score 2):

*At the moment* = now. "I'm in the garden with a cup of tea at the moment."

*At that moment* - "Mary unlocked the front door, and at that moment the telephone rang."

*At the time* = during the period when a past event happened. "I saw the Queen once. We were living in London at the time."

*At that time* is similar, but more likely to be used as part of a narrative. "At that time I had just moved to London."

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

At the time refers to something in the past.
At the time there were no smartphones.

The second is present time. 
At the moment I am busy finishing my homework.